# How to define a typed array of custom XML objects in Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I know it's possible to define a typed array of drawables in Android:

```
<array name="icons">
    <item>@drawable/home</item>
    <item>@drawable/settings</item>
    <item>@drawable/logout</item>
</array>
```

Is it possible to have an array of custom objects such as Styleable ones (this syntax doesn't work, FYI)?

```
<array name="custom_objects">
    <item>@styleable/home</item>
    <item>@styleable/settings</item>
    <item>@styleable/logout</item>
</array>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do it with xml, although I am not sure. I think you should create your array via code.